# How to get a query set where time property of objects cover the last day?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Accept my apologies I couldn't explain the question any better in the title.

I have a model like below:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The objects can be created at any time and have that time saved in created_time.

I want to filter all the objects that are created from just before yesterday until now.

So if we consider that we are at 22:00 now, and we have 5 objects from yesterday 22:00 until now, I also want the last object that is created before yesterday 22:00, and it can be created a month ago.

> The query below not work because it omits the last object before yesterday:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

yesterday = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)

objs = MyModel.objects.filter(created_time__gte=yesterday)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I hope I have explained the question clearly 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need to query the database twice.

```
counts = MyModel.objects.filter(created_time__gte=yesterday).count()
objs = MyModel.objects.order_by('-created_time')[:counts+1]
```

Comment: Thank you dear mehdy for your answer. It works! I hope you will be successful in virgool.io 